# Authenticating Swagger API docs (drf-yasg)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I've setup [DRF-YASG](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg) but am unable to figure out how to configure it to show Views that require Authentication.

Below is the configuration.

```
  schema_view = get_schema_view(
      openapi.Info(
        title="Swagger Doc",
        default_version='v1',
        description="Test description",
        terms_of_service="https://www.google.com/policies/terms/",
        contact=openapi.Contact(email="contact@snippets.local"),
        license=openapi.License(name="BSD License"),
      ),
      validators=['flex', 'ssv'],
      permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),  # If I change the permission it throws an exception. See below
      public=False,
      patterns=public_apis,
  )
```

the `public_apis` are the APIs that I want a person to see after they have authenticated themselves.

With the above configuration, it does not show a single API. It only shows the `Authorize` Button and text that says `No operations defined in spec!`. But if I change `public=False` to `public=True` then it shows all the APIs.

PS: Earlier I was using [Django Rest Swagger](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger) and I had been able to configure it to show the APIs only after the JWT token had been provided.

Am is using JWT for authentication.

**Exception on Permission Change:**

Another issue is that if I change the permission above to a DRF Permission class the rendering fails with the error below:

```
  Internal Server Error: /swagger/
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
      response = get_response(request)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
      response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
      response = response.render()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 107, in render
      self.content = self.rendered_content
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
      ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/drf_yasg/renderers.py", line 54, in render
      self.set_context(renderer_context, swagger)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/drf_yasg/renderers.py", line 62, in set_context
      renderer_context['title'] = swagger.info.title
  AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'info'
  Internal Server Error: /swagger/
```

I've tried changing it to `permmissions.IsAuthenticated` and my own custom permission classes but they all fail with the same error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turned out the issue was that I was missing `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` in DRF's `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`.

So the request object sent after logging in via the Django Admin login view did not have a user so all permission classes kept failing and it would then lead to the above error.

So after adding it drf-yasg shows all its glory.

**Bug:**

The error it throws when this occurs was raised as bug though. See [#issue58](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/58).

Answer (score 0):

### you should set the authentication class in schema view if you only use JWT:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
"DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
    ],
}
```

**so your schema view should be something like that:**

```
  schema_view = get_schema_view(
      openapi.Info(
        title="Swagger Doc",
        default_version='v1',
        description="Test description",
        terms_of_service="https://www.google.com/policies/terms/",
        contact=openapi.Contact(email="contact@snippets.local"),
        license=openapi.License(name="BSD License"),
      ),
    authentication_classes=(authentication.BasicAuthentication,),
    public=True,
  )
```

**it should work and ask you to set your username and password.**